# What is the shortcut to auto indent code in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I work with both C++ and Python, however `ctrl+k f` doesn't seem to auto-indent my code. Is there anything I might be missing?

If I need to install an extension that is OK, but I would prefer to use a built in method if there is one.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

I am wondering the same thing and find this native solution.

```
On Windows Shift + Alt + F
On Mac Shift + Option + F
On Ubuntu Ctrl + Shift + I
```

Ref:
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/how+to+auto+indent+in+visual+studio+code

Comment: on ubuntu = on debian

Answer (score 18):

1. Press **Ctrl+Shift+P** to open Command Palette. Type in settings and select Open User Settings.
2. In Search settings box, input **indent** to search for settings related to indentation. Select **full** in Editor: Auto Indent section.
3. Automatic indentation is now enabled. Changes are saved automatically and applies to all opened files as well.

But its better to install **plugins** like **linter** or **formatter** or **beautifier**
so you can use commands like  **Shift + Alt + F** to format your code

Answer (score 0):

if you go into Options > C/C++ > Code Style > General > When I paste,
the first option is "Indent and format".

so if you select all, cut, then paste, it should auto indent everything for you.
probably not the fanciest or most robust answer but it works for me.

Comment: Op is using visul studio CODE not visual studio. There's also no indication whether it's C++ or not.

Answer (score -6):

These solutions did not work for me in Ubuntu.

What worked for me was:

**Shift + tab**

Comment: Haha, this is not an "auto indent", this is a "backward TAB"